# Get Local Version before the last check in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am using TFS 2013 with Visual Studio online. Last day, I finished all my work and checked-in. There were some conflicts. I merged the conflicts and checked-in again. But when I open the app today, I found some methods missing. Is it possible to grab my local version just before the yesterday check-in?

Comment: Not unless you had the local copies shelved before you attempted to check-in? Are you opening the application from the same machine or another? 

If the methods are missing on the same machine and you haven't got a shelveset, what you have on your machine is all you have I am afraid

Comment: @HamidShahid, Thanks what do you mean by shelveset? I have just done a check-in

Comment: A shelveset is a version of the code stored on the server but not yet checked-in. If you have checked-in and overwritten local copies the local copies are gone now.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me and my colleagues as well. After you merged the conflict, merged files are your latest local files. If you have decided remove your changes during merging, your changes are gone for ever.

You must pay special attention next time you merge files. This also give you another hint: Don't rely on tools. You're responsible for files you checked in.